# Why is my motorcycle making a "bang/thud" noise when I shift?

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, shifting, gears

I used to shift properly without any hiccups before. Lately, I am hearing a "bang/thud" noise while I shift gear. Its mostly experienced in lower gears and it's really smooth in higher gears.

Why is this happening and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What make/model of motorcycle do you have? How many miles are on it?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things that can be causing this.

- **Engine/Trans oil** - depending on the motorcycle, if the oil level is low, it could cause noise when shifting.
- **Clutch adjustment** - If the clutch is not adjusted properly it will
  cause some noise when shifting.
- **Shifting too fast** - if you have gotten good at riding, you may be
  shifting the gear before you are getting the clutch lever pulled all
  the way.

I would suggest attempting to shift slower, and in proper sequence, to see if it resolves the issue. If not, then adjust the clutch properly. After that, if there is still an issue, take it to a mechanic. If you intend to do the work yourself, purchasing a service manual is a great investment.

Comment: I think shifting too fast is my problem because every other person who has ridden my bike has faced no such thing. The problem for me is how to correct myself, this way of shifting has gotten stored in as a muscle memory and it automatically happens and when ever I try to shift gear after pulling the clutch in completely, my foot wouldn't shift the gear on time.

Comment: We are unable to help with your habits. You will need to make an effort to relearn shifting. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility are the engine mountings or bushes - you should check them for tightness and possible wear.

Comment: That's not the cause I believe because no one else other than me has faced this. The shifting happens so fast that I can't actually tell if I am shifting after completely  pulling the clutch in or not. Is it possible for such a noise to be produced from transmission due to delay in shifting after pulling the clutch in?

Comment: If you know the cause - sort it and btw, if it is driving technique then there is a danger the question will be clossd